# Что такое прагматика в программировании?

Tags: информатика

Что означает термин прагматика в программировании? Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах, просто уже кучу страниц перерыл ни как не могу понять что это.

Comment: Этот термин непосредственно в программировании не используется. Загляните в словарь, https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/прагматика

Comment: расскажите хотя бы, где вам встретился этот _термин_?

Comment: @mymedia, вот [тут](https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/sintaksis-semantika-i-pragmatika) вычитал.

Comment: абсолютно то же самое, что и альтруистика, только в минус первой степени.